# Custom field separators in awk with regex: problem with leading spaces and commas

Tags: regex, awk

I have looked around on stackoverflow for a solution, I have found some related answers, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution to my doubt. I hope I am not asking a duplicate question.

Let us consider a file

```
cat > file << EOF
1 2  3 4, 5,, 6, 7
EOF
```

I want to use as separator an arbitrary number of commas and spaces. With awk, setting the field separator with F"[ ,]*", I obtain the desired result, i.e:

```
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $1}' file --> 1
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $2}' file --> 2
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $3}' file --> 3
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $4}' file --> 4
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $5}' file --> 5
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $6}' file --> 6
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $7}' file --> 7
```

However, if I have leading spaces I have a problem. For example:

with one leading space

```
cat > file << EOF
 1 2  3 4, 5,, 6, 7
EOF
```

I obtain

```
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $1}' file -->   
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $2}' file --> 1
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $3}' file --> 2
...
```

with two leading spaces the same

```
cat > file << EOF
  1 2  3 4, 5,, 6, 7
EOF
```

```
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $1}' file -->  
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $2}' file -->  1
awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $3}' file -->  2
...
```

and so forth.

However, the problem is not only with the spaces.
For example with

```
cat > file << EOF
1,2,3,
EOF
```

I have

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' file -->   1
awk -F"," '{print $2}' file -->   2
awk -F"," '{print $3}' file -->   3
awk -F"," '{print $4}' file -->
```

which is what I expect, but with

```
cat > file << EOF
,1,2,3
EOF
```

I get

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' file -->   
awk -F"," '{print $2}' file -->   1
awk -F"," '{print $3}' file -->   2
awk -F"," '{print $4}' file -->   3
```

and I do not understand why.

It seems that awk is treating the leading separators in a different way. Probably, I have misunderstood the regex syntax. Indeed, I do not understand why setting -F" " the leading spaces 
are treated in the proper way, whereas setting -F"[ ]*" I have the same problem.

In conclusion, these are my questions: why I am obtaining those results for leading spaces or leading commas, and what is the correct syntax to consider, as field separators, any number of commas and spaces, regardless if they are leading or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is some inconsistency, I guess for convenience.

The default delimiter ignores the leading/trailing spaces

```
$ echo " 1 2 " | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"--> "$i}'
1--> 1
2--> 2
```

setting `FS` to space behaves the same

```
$ echo " 1 2 " | awk -F' ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"--> "$i}'
1--> 1
2--> 2
```

however, the char set.

```
$ echo " 1 2 " | awk -F'[ ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"--> "$i}'
1-->
2--> 1
3--> 2
4-->
```

since there are 3 delimiters (so assumes four fields).  With the comma delimiter you won't get the default behavior, but just the last version.

If you want to mimic the default behavior for both comma and space, you need to write your own handling, something like this

```
$ echo "   ,1 2," | 
  awk -F'[ ,]+' 'NF{if($1=="") {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $(i-1)=$i; NF--} 
                    if($NF=="") NF--} 
                   {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"--> "$i}'

1--> 1
2--> 2
```

**Explanation:**
if the first field is empty, shift all the fields to one left, reduce the field count by one; similarly if the last field is empty, simply reduce the field count. The last statement is for printing the fields one at a line by field position number.

**Update**
to handle empty lines add a guard `NF` before attempting to fix the fields.

Comment: OK, thank you. So it is an inconsistency of awk, not my misunderstanding of something. Do you have any suggestion about how to solve my problem, i.e. how to define as field separator any number of commas/spaces, regardless of their position? I am not able to set comma and spaces as field separators and discard the anomaly of leading spaces.

Comment: @Gippo I had misunderstood your question (hence I'll delete my answer); however I think that the first two examples in this answer are the anomaly, or the special case, and that the third one is the norm.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks, it works. However, I am not able to understand everything. Cold you explain a bit more how it works? If the first field is empty $1="", then it makes a loop over the fields to give the "name" i-1 to the i-th field, and it also reduces by one the number of fields, NF--. Then it checks again if $1=""? It applies a recursive check? I do not understand why this happens. This is how awk works? If I want to write a clause that is checked only once, how could I write it? Moreover, why is it necessary to do the second step, where if $NF="" then it reduces NF by 1?

Comment: @Enrico Maria De Angelis I don't understand why you say so. The field separators, by name, are like walls, that exists only to separate the contents, which are numbered. A field separator, a "wall", is not a field, thus it does not have a number. Indeed, it does not have it in the general case. If the string is 1,2 and the field separator is ",", then $1=1 and $2=2, whereas according to your interpretation, it should be $2="" and $3=2, which is against any usefulness of the field separator concept. By now, I consider this weird behavior of awk as a bug.

Comment: @Gippo, I think there is some misunderstanding between me and you. What I am saying is that, for instance, `,,,` (three commas) is a line of a 4-columns CSV file, and the 4 values are all empty strings. Do you agree with this? If you do, than it should be clear that if a line is `1,2` and `FS==","`, then `$1 == "1"` and `$2 == "2"`. But, if the line is `,1`, then `$1 == ""` and `$2 == "1"`.

Comment: @karakfa OK, thanks for the explanation. Your script does not work well if the file that awk is scanning has, among several strings, an empty string, because it complains that NF has a negative value. However, I guess one has just to add another check in the code to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Gippo I think another approach would be trimming out any leading and trailing separators (maybe with `sed`), and piping the output into a "normal" `awk` script.